# bash: --dbs command not found & others

Tags: bash, sqlmap

I am doing some pentests against one of my websites that is currently being built (a school project)

And I am trying to make sure it's security at it's best.

(Yes, I do have the correct parameters and the site is vulnerable to SQLi Injections.

It does continue it's scan but it will then ask the [y/n] and I choose [y] and it just stops and doesn't scan. I've tried doing a fresh clone of sqlmap and that didn't work.

Anything that can help would be appreciated.

```
root@kali:~# sqlmap -u http://myschoolproject.com/ --dbs
[1] 1372
bash: --dbs: command not found

(It will scan until asked a [y/n])



it looks like the back-end DBMS is 'MySQL'. Do you want to skip test payloads specific for other DBMSes? [Y/n] y

[1]+  Stopped sqlmap -u http://myschoolproject.com/
```

Comment: What's the actual url (you can replace the host by `example.com`)? Does it contain a `&` somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I forgot to include it when editing the code and replacing my site with a random one. It's ( index.php?cat=4 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like you have a `&` in there. In bash, `foo & bar` runs the command `foo` in the background and `bar` in the foreground.

So if your URL actually looks like `http://myschoolproject.com/index.php?cat=4&attr=95,76`, that command is interpreted as

```
sqlmap -u http://myschoolproject.com/index.php?cat=4 &
attr=95,76 --dbs
```

The first command runs `sqlmap` in the background (with a truncated URL); this explains the `[1] 1372` part (that's what bash shows then starting a background process). The second command runs `--dbs` in the foreground (with `attr` set to `95,76` in the environment); this explains the `bash: --dbs: command not found` error.

In any case, the solution is to quote the URL with single quotes:

```
sqlmap -u 'http://myschoolproject.com/index.php?cat=4&attr=95,76' --dbs
```

Comment: Edit: That worked perfectly. Thank you, Melpomene!